# Unity3D BackgroundDwonload Show Progress

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, github

There is a repository from Unity-Technologies here:

https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/BackgroundDownload

I have used the plugin, I can do a downloading operation and itcompletes successfully, but the progress won't get updated and displayed during the download:

```
 using (var download = Unity.Networking.BackgroundDownload.Start(new Uri(URL), Application.persistentDataPath+"/temp/assets"))
        {
            while (download.progress <=1.0f) 
            {
                percent = download.progress * 100; 
                DownloadProgressbar.GetComponent<Progressbar>().SetValue((int)percent);
                yield return null;
            }

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);


            if (download.status == Unity.Networking.BackgroundDownloadStatus.Failed)
            {
                Debug.Log(download.error);
            }
            else
            {
                showAlert('download is finished');
            }
}
```

It does not give me the progress of my download operation. also I have used

```
yield return new download
```

but it doesn't work. at final step it gives 1.0 as progress but during the download, I can't get the download progress.

Any Idea ?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: any chance it down loads in < 0.5s?

Comment: @BugFinder, Not at all.., since after some seconds the complete message is appearing, I'm sure that download takes more than ten seconds. ( in the actual code, I have a conditional statement like 'error check' in above code... that checks if the download is completed and logs a message to the user..